# Flutter app crashes on entering one particular screen only

Tags: android, ios, flutter, crash

I'm developing an e-commerce application, and on entering the product details screen, the app gets stuck at loading , and then crashes after a while, it doesn't show any specific app related, error which I can recognize and work on, neither is there any error on tha backend, the API responses load perfectly.

And this happens on both Android emulators and iOS simulator, same on real devices as well.

The console logs shows -

```
I/scudo   ( 7103): Scudo OOM: The process has exhausted 256M for size class 11664.
```

[image]

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: Do you perhaps have some list there that you are trying to show, and you have too much data there maybe. If that is the case, I would test it with short version of the same list first.

Comment: @SadatD no I have just a list of images(CarouselSlider), and it has 2-3 images only...

Comment: Maybe sharing the code for the screen would help ? This is way its not really possible to figure out what is causing the crash

Comment: https://codeshare.io/gLBrE8 @amirala7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So solved it, it was a ListView.builder I had been using to show the product reviews(the section which I was least expecting to be the culprit), nested deep inside my widget tree that was actually causing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
dart pub cache clean
```

and:

```
flutter clean
```

Then run:

```
dart pub upgrade
```

and try rebuilding your project for the target platform.

I hope it works

Comment: tried, no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is in your productDetailsProvider. Since you did not provide the detail about it, I think your code did not set the state to `ProductDetailsSuccessState` after fetching successfully and you then it kept loading

Comment: https://codeshare.io/MNr0o3 - here's the code - I did set success state

Comment: @AmaniSaaduddin Did you call to `fetchProductDetails` function ?

Comment: Yeah I did, on tapping the product card

Comment: @AmaniSaaduddin That's not the way you should do. Instead, you should call `fetchProductDetails` in the initState of the detail screen. Give it a try

Comment: Why is that not the way? I usually do so, so that the app load times will seem faster.
Btw, I found the issue, it was a ListView builder causing it.